# Stop converting "<" to "&lt;" in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have jsp page and some set of javascript code written inside the jsp page.

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
//some stuff
}
```

but in the browser its giving error and the rendered code look like

> for(i=0; `i&lt;10;` i++ { }

how to stop converting "<" to "`&lt;`".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Is your JS code meant to be executed, or just displayed as it is?

If you have the former situation, is your code inside `<script type="text/javascript">...</script>` tags?

If you have the latter situation, then characters such as `<` HAVE to be converted to `&lt`, otherwise they would be read as HTML tags by your browser.

Comment: yes. My code inside the <script type="text/javascript">... </script> but still the problem exists :(

Comment: They do not necessarily **have** to be converted in HTML. Only XML/XHTML requires that. But the OP would then have an got entirely different error (not well formed XML).

Answer (score 1):

JSP does by default not do that. Aren't you *actually* using JSTL `<c:out>` to print JavaScript code? It can namely do that. You could disable that by adding `escapeXml="false"` attribute.

Anyway, best would always be to put JS code in its own `.js` file which you then include in the head as follows:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: where to add escapeXml="false"

Comment: The `<c:out>` tag like so: `<c:out value="blah" escapeXml="false"/>`. Only if you were already using `<c:out>` (which is technically not the right way to write JavaScript in JSP anyway). By the way, in your rendered code excerpt an `)` is missing. Is this also true in real?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps....

```
function toHtml(myString)
{
    htmlString = myString.split("&lt;").join("<");
    htmlString = htmlString.split("&gt;").join(">");
    htmlString = htmlString.split("&quot;").join("\"");
    htmlString = htmlString.split("&apos;").join("\'");
    return htmlString;
}
```

Gretting.
Víctor